# I Got an Error about Loading the Model (UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 32: invalid start byte)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I was applying this linked appliaction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lH01BgsIPuE I got an error like this:

```
PS C:\Users\mfurk\OneDrive\Masaüstü\FR> python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mfurk\OneDrive\Masaüstü\FR\test.py", line 17, in <module>
model = load_model('keras_model.h5')
File "C:\Users\mfurk\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\saving_api.py", line 212, in load_model
return legacy_sm_saving_lib.load_model(
File "C:\Users\mfurk\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "C:\Users\mfurk\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 703, in is_directory_v2
return _pywrap_file_io.IsDirectory(compat.path_to_bytes(path))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 32: invalid start byte
```

Here are my error lines:

> line 17: model = load_model('keras_model.h5')

> line 212: return legacy_sm_saving_lib.load_model(
> filepath, custom_objects=custom_objects, compile=compile, **kwargs
> )

line 70: def filter_traceback(fn):
"""Filter out Keras-internal stack trace frames in exceptions raised by
fn."""
if sys.version_info.major != 3 or sys.version_info.minor < 7:
return fn

```
def error_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    if not tf.debugging.is_traceback_filtering_enabled():
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    filtered_tb = None
    try:
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as e:
        filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
        # To get the full stack trace, call:
        # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    finally:
        del filtered_tb

return tf.__internal__.decorator.make_decorator(fn, error_handler)
```

line 703: @tf_export("io.gfile.isdir")
def is_directory_v2(path):
"""Returns whether the path is a directory or not.

Args:
path: string, path to a potential directory

Returns:
True, if the path is a directory; False otherwise
"""
try:
return _pywrap_file_io.IsDirectory(compat.path_to_bytes(path))
except errors.OpError:
return False